# Pandoc breaks table headers when converting HTML (exported from Confluence) to Github Flavored Markdown

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc, confluence, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to convert HTML pages from our Confluence Wiki to Github Flavored Markdown for the Github Wiki.

I want to remove all formatting to get a "vanilla" Markdown output without embedded HTML. I settled on this command for the moment:

```bash
pandoc failing_table_tidy_reduced.html -f html-native_divs-native_spans -t gfm-raw_html -o failing_table_tidy_reduced.md
```

**(The contents of `failing_table_tidy_reduced.html` are pasted below.)**

The Markdown output is OK for the most part, except that the table headers are systematically broken. I get this for the example file that is pasted below:

```
|                                                |                                               |                                                                                                                                                         |
|------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Step 1: Select to open image as virtual stack. | Step 2: Select image folder and open dataset. | Step 3: View with opened image stack. Use the slider of in the phase contrast histogram (top) to adjust image saturation for better channel visibility. |
| ![](attachments/314948158/314950704.png)       | ![](attachments/314948158/314950710.png)      | ![](attachments/314948158/314950785.png)                                                                                                                |
```

Whereas I expect the text (ie. "Step N: ...") to be in the table header, like so:

```
| Step 1: Select to open image as virtual stack. | Step 2: Select image folder and open dataset. | Step 3: View with opened image stack. Use the slider of in the phase contrast histogram (top) to adjust image saturation for better channel visibility. |
|------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ![](attachments/314948158/314950704.png)       | ![](attachments/314948158/314950710.png)      | ![](attachments/314948158/314950785.png)                                                                                                                |
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

This is the content of `failing_table_tidy_reduced.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.6.0">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/site.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type='text/css'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
div.rbtoc1689000519714 {padding: 0px;}
div.rbtoc1689000519714 ul {margin-left: 0px;}
div.rbtoc1689000519714 li {margin-left: 0px;padding-left: 0px;}

/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body class="theme-default aui-theme-default">
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="wrapped relative-table confluenceTable" style=
"width: 48.0112%;">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 27.3364%;">
<col style="width: 28.271%;">
<col style="width: 44.3925%;"></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="confluenceTh">
<p>Step 1: Select to open image as virtual stack.</p>
</th>
<th class="confluenceTh">
<p>Step 2: Select image folder and open dataset.</p>
</th>
<th class="confluenceTh">Step 3: View with opened image stack. Use
the slider of in the phase contrast histogram (top) to adjust image
saturation for better channel visibility.</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<p><span class=
"confluence-embedded-file-wrapper confluence-embedded-manual-size"><img class="confluence-embedded-image confluence-thumbnail"
draggable="false" height="250" src=
"attachments/314948158/314950704.png" data-image-src=
"attachments/314948158/314950704.png"
data-unresolved-comment-count="0" data-linked-resource-id=
"314950704" data-linked-resource-version="1"
data-linked-resource-type="attachment"
data-linked-resource-default-alias="image2022-4-26_15-0-46.png"
data-base-url="https://my.url.com"
data-linked-resource-content-type="image/png"
data-linked-resource-container-id="314948158"
data-linked-resource-container-version="61" alt=""></span></p>
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<p><span class=
"confluence-embedded-file-wrapper confluence-embedded-manual-size"><img class="confluence-embedded-image confluence-thumbnail"
draggable="false" height="250" src=
"attachments/314948158/314950710.png" data-image-src=
"attachments/314948158/314950710.png"
data-unresolved-comment-count="0" data-linked-resource-id=
"314950710" data-linked-resource-version="1"
data-linked-resource-type="attachment"
data-linked-resource-default-alias="image2022-4-26_15-1-20.png"
data-base-url="https://my.url.com"
data-linked-resource-content-type="image/png"
data-linked-resource-container-id="314948158"
data-linked-resource-container-version="61" alt=""></span></p>
</div>
</td>
<td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<p><span class=
"confluence-embedded-file-wrapper confluence-embedded-manual-size"><img class="confluence-embedded-image"
draggable="false" height="250" src=
"attachments/314948158/314950785.png" data-image-src=
"attachments/314948158/314950785.png"
data-unresolved-comment-count="0" data-linked-resource-id=
"314950785" data-linked-resource-version="1"
data-linked-resource-type="attachment"
data-linked-resource-default-alias="image2022-4-26_15-12-47.png"
data-base-url="https://my.url.com"
data-linked-resource-content-type="image/png"
data-linked-resource-container-id="314948158"
data-linked-resource-container-version="61" alt=""></span></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```